# Doing git clone with bash script, could not read Password for repository

Tags: linux, bash, git, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to deploy Amazon EC2 instance through CloudFormation and I'm trying to clone a repository with a bash script with cfn-init.

```
"UserData" : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                "#! /bin/bash -xe\n",
                "yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap\n",
                "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
                "       --stack ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" },
                "       --resource DocumentationInstance ",
                "       --configsets Install ",
                "       --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n",
                "git clone https://", { "Ref": "GitLabUsn" },"@gitlab.com/user/repository.git \n", { "Ref": "GitLabPwd" }  
                ]]}}
        }
```

However, when I deploy the EC2 instance, I can see from `cloud-init-output.log` that the git clone fails, and this is the error:

```
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://username@gitlab.com': No such device or address
```

How can I input the password with the bash script correctly? I've tried the `yes` found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338857/automatically-enter-input-in-command-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADD the password like this(your can also set it as parameter)
`git clone https://user:password@gitlab.com/....git`

In your case, it will be :

```
"git clone https://", { "Ref": "GitLabUsn" },":", { "Ref": "GitLabPwd" },"@gitlab.com/user/repository.git \n"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment! I've tried as well, but I get this error when trying this out.


fatal: unable to access https:// username:pwd@gitlab.com/user/repo.git : Illegal port number